# disabling HTML.TextBoxFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Student.FirstName, new { id = "FirstName", disabled = "disabled" })

I wanted to disable the the text box so i used disabled attr as above and it worked but upon saving the form, the value loaded in above textbox turns to null.

any body have a idea of what is going on

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by design. Disabled inputs don't POST back to the server.

You can make the input 'read only' by using 'readonly'. This will let the data be POSTED back, but the user cannot edit the information in the traditional fashion.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Some Value" readonly="readonly" />
```

Keep in mind that people can use a tool like Firebug or Dragonfly to edit the data and post it back. So keep on your toes and either make sure the data is the same, or better yet, just use the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this in @Html.TextBoxFor

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Student.FirstName, new { id = "FirstName", ,@readonly="readonly" })
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML spec says that disabled inputs do not POST their values. You'll need to create a hidden input to accompany this value if you want to persist it client-side.

However, this may not be what you want. If you've disabled the textbox, you probably don't intend for the user to be able to change this value, but there is nothing preventing their using Firebug or a similar browser tool to re-enable the input and send a different value. You're probably better off populating this value on the model server-side using the same method you used to get it in the first place.